# Create `Table` where each line is a function of the line before

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I've been noodling around with primitive Pythagorean triples. One of the 'branches' of the ternary tree that generates all possible PPTs from the initial parent PPT `3,4,5` is given by

```
Subscript[a, i + 1] = 
 Subscript[a, i] - 2*Subscript[b, i] + 2*Subscript[c, i]; 
Subscript[b, i + 1] = 
 2*Subscript[a, i] - Subscript[b, i] + 2*Subscript[c, i]; 
Subscript[c, i + 1] = 
 2*Subscript[a, i] - 2*Subscript[b, i] + 3*Subscript[c, i];
```

I want to make a table where each row of `3` numbers, starting with the (given) root PPT `Subscript[a, 1]=3,Subscript[b, 1]=4,Subscript[c, 1]=5`, is produced by the application of those formulas to the row immediately preceding so that `{3,4,5}->{5,12,13}->{7,24,25}->{9,40,41}` etc, giving

```
table={{3,4,5},{5,12,13},{7,24,25},{9,40,41},{...}}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `NestList`.

Comment: Hi @Kuba. Yep, I suspect that'll do it. Appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Kuba. OK, obviously being stupid here. I need more help... I get what `NestList` is doing in principle, but not sure how to make it into the `Table` I'm after. `a = 3; b = 4; c = 5;
NestList[{a - 2 b + 2 c, 2 a - b + 2 c, 2 a - 2 b + 3 c} &, 0, 4]` just produces strings of identical digits, for example.

Comment: try `NestList[{#[[1]]-2#[[2]]+2#[[3]],2#[[1]]-#[[2]]+2#[[3]],2#[[1]]-2#[[2]]+3#[[3]]}&,{3,4,5},3] `

Comment: That works, so I'll take it! Haven;'t go the hang of using `#` yet, but if it ain't broke... Thanks @J42161217. (Got it now!)

Comment: Or RecurrenceTable