# Conditional formatting of table

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, conditional

I have a table (from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197898/create-table-where-each-line-is-a-function-of-the-line-before)) as follows:

```
NestList[{#[[1]] - 2 #[[2]] + 2 #[[3]], 2 #[[1]] - #[[2]] + 2 #[[3]], 
2 #[[1]] - 2 #[[2]] + 3 #[[3]]} &, {3, 4, 5}, 15]// TableForm
```

I want the same table, but with all instances where the second column is divisible by `8` to be highlighted as `Style[numberDivisibleBy8,Bold]`. It doesn't work to add an `If` function to the `#` expressions. So, how do I do it?

Comment: Please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194053/create-bold-headings-and-rows-in-tableform-if-x-is-prime

Comment: Hi @MelaGo. I looked again (it was my own question, after all!) , but I really don't see how to transfer that to the current table. I tried, and just ended up with a garbled mess. I realise these are Newbie issues, but I just don't (yet) get it. I'll work on my understanding, but I was hoping for a solution for right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = NestList[{#[[1]] - 2 #[[2]] + 2 #[[3]], 
     2 #[[1]] - #[[2]] + 2 #[[3]], 
     2 #[[1]] - 2 #[[2]] + 3 #[[3]]} &, {3, 4, 5}, 15];

t2 = Table[Style[#, {Bold, Plain}[[IntegerQ[row[[2]]/8] /. {True -> 1, False -> 2}]]] & /@row, {row, t}]
```

or

```
t2 = Table[Style[#, If[IntegerQ[row[[2]]/8], Bold, Plain]] & /@ row, {row, t}]
```

```
TableForm[t2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 NestList[{#[[1]] - 2 #[[2]] + 2 #[[3]], 2 #[[1]] - #[[2]] + 2 #[[3]], 
          2 #[[1]] - 2 #[[2]] + 3 #[[3]]} &, {3, 4, 5}, 15] // 
    MapAt[If[Divisible[#, 8], Style[#, Red, Bold], #] &, #, {All, 2}] & // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Both great answers, but I had to go with the one I was closest to understanding. Much appreciated, both of you.